# Creating external apps Wordpress / How they work

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, api, third-party-applications

I was wondering how does external app works for `wordpress.com` or `wordpress.org`.

Directly connecting to the wordpress database seems a bad idea to me.

Questions

- How can I create an app or get / post data from the wordpress database?
- Is there a JSON API or XML API format so that I can easily exchange data between the two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WordPress features a very rich XML-RPC interface that you can work with from external applications.  It provides you access to most of the functionality you'd have directly in the admin - write posts, edit posts, edit comments, create/edit categories, manage site options, upload files, etc.

As a matter of fact, certain third-party applications are already using this functionality to allow you to manage WordPress remotely - a good example is [Windows Live Writer](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-writer?os=other).  It works for both self-hosted (.org) sites and sites hosted on WordPress.com.

So if you need to get posts from WordPress, I'd recommend following API calls:

- **metaWeblog.getPost** - for retrieving a single post based on its ID.
- **metaWeblog.getRecentPosts** - for retrieving a list of recently published posts

You can also create/edit posts with these API calls:

- **metaWeblog.newPost** - create a new post
- **metaWeblog.editPost** - edit an existing post

There's more information about creating your own application (and an explanation as to why WordPress supports third-party APIs like metaWeblog) in [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support).

I've also written tutorials on [how to use the API](http://mindsharestrategy.com/wpxmlrpc-using-the-api/) and documentation specific to making/parsing [metaWeblog API](http://mindsharestrategy.com/wp-xmlrpc-metaweblog/) requests.

Answer (score 1):

For self-hosted WordPress blogs, you can use the [JSON API plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/). I'm working with it on a project right now... it's fairly full-featured OOB, and it's extensible. [Documentation is here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/other_notes/).

Not sure about wordpress.com blogs.